# Autodesk Application Platform's Design Automation Does Not Work (Problem occurs at createBundle)

Tags: autodesk-forge

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7In7O.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSmEN.png)
[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUilr.png)  I was trying to follow this tutorial: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/design-automation/
to connect my localhost server with APS. I tried both their dotnet and nodejs repo. At both case, it causes problem when creating the bundle. I attached the the screenshots of the error.

In the localhost interface, when I select a local AppBundle(UpdateRVTParam in this case), select an engine and then click on Create/Update, it shows "Defining appbundle and activity for Autodesk.Revit+2021" and then the error occurs.
I have tried different versions, and all my login credentials are ok (Client ID, Secret) cause, before the appBundle creation, it made some other http request with the credentials and those were accepted, like showing a list of engines. The problem occur when it needs to create activities. I have also tried deleting/clearing the app data so that it does not conflict.

Can anyone fix it?

I have attached the dotnet error.

Comment: I dont see the attachment you referred to? Might assist in finding the cause of the error

Comment: Can't upload image here, attached the link now. Please check, first 2 images are when using dotnet, and the third one is when using nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to `git clone` the full sample and try out.
for .NET
https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-design-automation-dotnet

for .Node.JS

https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-design-automation-nodejs

Comment: I did those. It had some problems, I contracted with their team and they are trying to solve it. The solution was, new app had to create a nickname  by using their APIs and sending a Post Request and hard code the nickname in the GetNickName() method as return string.